# How is bash commandline stdin propagated to child process

Tags: bash

I have a script (`file_redirection.sh`), where I have tried various combinations to get what I want:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "cat " $*
echo "cat $*"
echo "cat $@"
echo "cat " $@
```

I would like to be able to run

```
file_redirection.sh < tmp_file
```

And have it show

```
"cat < tmp_file"
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask "how it works".  UNIX processes are created using an action known as `fork`.  This takes a copy of the *current* process and copies it almost exactly as it is, in a very efficient manner.  Copying also includes the file descriptor table, where stdin, stdout, stderr, live.

When you do redirection, the shell forks, then alters it's own file descriptor (fd) table in the child.  It then runs the new script with the same fd table in the same process.  Using conventional mechanisms, the only thing that a process can check is if stdin is connected to a terminal or not.  In C it uses `isatty()` and in bash you can `if [[ -t 0 ]]...` (zero is the fd for stdin).

In Linux (if you are using Linux) you have an additional option, the fd table is presented in a readable form in `/proc/$$/fd` ($$ give the current proces id).  `ls -l /proc/$$/fd` and you will see what I mean.

So, am I redirected?

```
if [[ -t 0 ]]   # is stdin a terminal?
then
    suffix=""
else
    line=$(ls -l /proc/$$/fd/0)
    file="${line##*-> }"

    suffix="< $file"
fi

echo "cat $suffix"
```

On the commandline:

```
/home/user1$ file_redirection.sh < tmp_file
cat < /home/qa/tmp_file
```

BUT.  Why on earth do you want to do that?

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  After I asked, I had come across [ -t 0 ], but I didn't know about the fd table.
I want this because qrsh doesn't seem to do well with redirected stdin, but if I give the redirection in the command I give to qrsh then all is fine.  `qrsh "cmd" < input` (doesn't work sometimes) vs `qrsh "cmd <input"`

Comment: Note to self: I almost filed a new question regarding why `file` was pointing to a file with `(deleted)` appended, but over the weekend that issue seems to have resolved itself.

Answer (score 6):

No, that's not possible.  The `<` on your command line is interpreted by the shell before your script ever runs.  You need to escape the `<` to get it into your script.  For example:

```
file_redirection.sh \< tmp_file
```

will generate the output you're looking for, but *does not* do any file redirection.

Comment: While this answers my question of 'Is it possible?' (which is why I marked it as correct), it doesn't help me pass the redirected stdin to the child process.  Should I ask this as a separate question or edit this question?

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

`file_redirection.sh "< tmp_file"`

and in your file this:

`echo "cat $1"`

OR

`file_redirection.sh \< tmp_file`

and in your file this:

`echo "cat $*"`

Comment: You're changing the input to get the desired output, rather than (impossibly, as it turns out) changing the script to produce the desired output from the given input.